# Spring Boot: Could not locate field name [companyId] on class [...Entity]

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a question:

Here is my entity:

```
public class CompanyBindingEntity {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "BINDING_ID", nullable = false)
     private int companyBindingId;
 
     @NotNull
     @Embedded
     @Valid
     private CompanyEntity company; 
    ....
}
```

Here is CompanyEntity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
@Builder
@Data
public class CompanyEntity {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    private Integer companyId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "COMPANY_NAME")
    private String companyName;    
}
```

And I want to implement

```
findByCompanyId(int companyId)
```

method in my service and repository. But I am receiving this error:

> `Could not locate field name [companyId] on class [...Entity]`

because the `companyId` is inside `CompanyEntity`, not in `CompanyBindingEntity`. I need to find a way about how to solve this. Am I missing a special annotation to search for a nested element?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: maybe you meant "companyBindingId"?

Comment: no actually, that would be easy. I am trying to find by a field which is inside CompanyEntity.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define an association between CompanyBindingEntity and CompanyEntity, for example:

```
 @NotNull
 @Embedded
 @Valid
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetchType = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
 private CompanyEntity company;
```

Then in the table that holds CompanyBindingEntity define a foreign key to bind "COMPANY_ID" to the ID for CompanyEntity.

Comment: I updated the question, could you check my entity again?

Comment: My answer still applies - add `@OneToOne` and `@JoinColumn` annotations as I described. Please note that you will need to have column for COMPANY_ID in the CompanyBindingEntity table as well. Then in the CompanyBindingEntity table define a foreign key to bind its "COMPANY_ID" with "COMPANY_ID" in CompanyEntity table. Only then you will be able to implement the method you're asking about.